# How to know from where to import and the message type?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS, wanted to experiment with publishing and subscribing. The basic codes available are easy to run.
Now let us say I have downloaded a package, My_Pkg, in its msg folder there is a file my_msg.msg  where they have defined a message by name MSG.

My question is how do i publish or subscribe for this message:
The simple statement : pub=rospy.Publisher('topic_name', MSG)
Results in error that MSG is not defined.
If I import: from My_Pkg.MSG import MSG
Still error no module named Console.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248997/how-to-know-from-where-to-import-and-the-message-type?/) by [kapoor_amita](https://answers.ros.org/users/28643/kapoor_amita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it:
First Run rosmsg list, it will list all the messages, choose the one you were looking for so in above case it is simply:
from my_pkg.msg import MSG
and it works

---

Originally posted by [kapoor_amita](https://answers.ros.org/users/28643/kapoor_amita/) with karma: 26 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0